# How to save 2 strings in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-widget, save, sharedpreferences

I have a contact name in my widget configuration class and i save it with the following code:

```
String name= mAppWidgetPrefix.getText().toString();
save(context, mAppWidgetId, name);

static void save(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
prefs.commit();
}
```

I load it with this:

```
static String load(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String prefix = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);

return prefix;

}
```

It works fine, but i want to save the phone number too. How do I need to change the code?

```
String numberPrefix = pickedNumber.getText().toString(); //I need to save this too
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify another key for saving. Like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY_NUMBER + appWidgetId, text);
prefs.commit();
```

Comment: your answer was helpful. I have another problem, but I don't find a solution. Please check it if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025290/displaying-contacts-photo-by-photo-id